# Running reports from busy tables and avoiding locking those tables

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a number of reports involving joins on large datasets.  These tables are being written to many times per second.  My cronjobs run the queries at the least impactful times but still I am concerned about harming performance by locking tables with them.

Here is a simple example they requested as a one off today.  It shows playtimes for a RIIA report:

```
SELECT  
    date_format(p.`played`, '%Y-%m') as `month`,
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(s.`length`))/3600 as `playtime`
INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/120313_playtime.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM 
    `plays` p,
    `songs` s
GROUP BY `month`
```

How do I construct this to avoid causing issues for the radio app writing to the plays table while the query is running?  Should I create temp tables and copy the live ones over?

// EDIT per request EXPLAIN output

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3909 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4040933 | Using join buffer               |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+

CREATE TABLE `plays` (
  `play_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `song_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `played` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`play_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4040992 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='play counts for songs' AUTO_INCREMENT=4040992 ;


CREATE TABLE `songs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `length` time NOT NULL,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `tracknum` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `bitrate` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4136 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4136 ;
```

Comment: can you show an `EXPLAIN` from your query above ?

Comment: Added EXPLAIN to main body now.  Tables both have an auto-incremented id field.

Comment: so the tables are related ie using foreign keys ?? can you add a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both too ?

Comment: @ManseUK yes, plays.song_id references songs.id.  Creates added

Comment: @jerrygarciuh I dont see any foreign key constraints ?!?

Comment: @jerrygarciuh investigate / read up about indexes - this will ensure you query runs more efficiently ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two immediate things come to mind...  One, no "JOIN" between plays and songs which will result in a Cartesian product.  Second, add a WHERE clause, and I would expect the "played" column is a date/time, so you could query for all records < NOW(), so if any are added while the query is running, they would be excluded.  Since it appears you are doing monthly, you might even create a separate table that is nothing but the running totals per "time period" grouped by month and year, then you don't have to worry about a super long query.  Then, you can just run for the current month in question... still less than NOW().